# Cannot connect remotely to my SQL server remotely

Tags: mysql, sql-server, networking

Well, first off, I am no programmer. I am a medstudent with decent computer knowledge, and that has done this at least one time before in his home network.

Now, i am doing some research at the hospital, and for my database i want to use mysql, running a server on a local network computer and being able to connect to it from laptops over wi-fi to work on the database.

So i download mysql installe, run it, and i connect via localhost perfectly well with the root acc or the set up accounts i will use. I do bind-address to change its ip to the computers IP on the network, and i can connect again with root and with my accounts perfectly well on the machine the same server is on, using xx.xx.xx.xx + port to connect, with root and all other users.

however, using workbench on a laptop connected to the local network, I cannot connect with any user, it always gives error 10060.

--Firewall is off
--All AV software is off
--accounts are set up correctly to allow connection from any host 
--client PC can ping server PC 
--Netstat -anob shows mysqld.exe listening on the port i need it to be listening

The network here does block connections, but the port im using is open due to the fact it is used for another server type application that as very little to no traffic, so i just grabbed the opened ports for that application as they showed up in netstat and configured te server to use one of those ports.

How can i make sure the server PC is open at those ports?

THe client im trying to connect with is either the mysql workbench or heidisql. 
Neither can connect, however i have succesfully used heidi before to connect to a database I have in DB4free.net. I cannot use that at the hospital, because the network shuts off the default port for mysql which is what db4free.net uses.

Any ideas why i cant connect to that PC?

Comment: Your question isn't really appropriate for Stack Overflow, you may be better asking it on SuperUser (http://superuser.com/).

Comment: thanks, Ill ask there too, but the level of the answers there.... don't seem to be what i need. I've looked high and low in here and no answer yet. I know its not an exact programming question, buts its not as easy as the doubts of people un superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mySQL often does not come configured for remote connections by default. The port may be open, but if mySQL isn't listening or is set to reject all remote connections, you won't be able to connect.

Check the documentation for your version of mySQL to find out how to modify your mySQL server's configuration to allow remote connections.

Comment: well, I've read almost all the documentation, and theres is no specific setting to allow remote connections. in the my.ini file all the ignore settings are commented out, and all the user are properly configured, which is what most people suggest quickly. Also, the netstat program on the windows shell does show up tht my server is listening. mysqld.exe at the assigned port. Shouldn't that be enough indication it is listening? wireless isolation in the router is already ruled out. I need more options. netbios is enabled, and im running out of reason as to why I can remote access the database?

Comment: @MaxMolina I'll dig on the remote connections a bit. Can you post the exact error message you get?

Comment: @MaxMolina In the meantime, look for the `bind-address 127.0.0.1` and `skip-networking` lines in my.ini and make sure they're commented out. Also double check the user's privileges to make sure they're set to use the IP of the client server (or wild card) and that the privileges have been flushed. Your error message may give more clues, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: Just revised user privileges, they are well set but I just had it with this. As for an exac error, the only number heidi shows is 10060. the mysql console flashe very quickly and I think it says error 2003. How ever im changing the approach. I'll install a apache server, WAMP 3, and lets sql fight itself in the local way, and use a proper server structure to work it out. That will allow me to use myphpadmin and I can also install a browser db manager very easily. Wish me luck.  The lines you mntioned are indeed commented out.

Comment: Error 2003 is another [connection error](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,99347,99358). I know you're trying a new tack, but I have to wonder...can you telnet from the client to the server on the mySQL port (usually 3306, but depends on your config)? Good luck either way!